# How to check if two round divs are overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, overlapping

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexios-leonidas/pen/oNqQZqM). I want to check if the divs are overlapping each other with jQuery. I wrote a code for that but it doesn't work with round boxes. it only works with squares  and rectangles. how can I make it work with round divs?

```js
const coordinates = (className) => {
  const val = document.querySelector(className);
  
  return {
      y: val.offsetTop,
      x: val.offsetLeft,
      yh: val.offsetTop + val.offsetHeight,
      xw: val.offsetLeft + val.offsetWidth,
  }
}

const cm = coordinates(".circle.small");
const cl = coordinates(".circle.large");

const offset_x = cm.x < cl.x && cm.xw > cl.x;
const offset_xw = cm.x < cl.xw && cm.xw > cl.xw;
const offset_cx = cm.x < cl.xw && cm.xw < cl.xw;
const offset_cy = cm.y < cl.yh && cm.yh < cl.yh;
const offset_y = cm.y < cl.y && cm.yh > cl.y;
const offset_yh = cm.y < cl.yh && cm.yh > cl.yh;

const is_x = offset_x || offset_xw || offset_cx;
const is_y = offset_y || offset_yh || offset_cy;

console.log(is_x, is_y);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: var(--square);
  height: var(--square);
  background: var(--bg);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.parent {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.parent2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.small {
  --square: 50px;
  --bg: red;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.large {
  --square: 100px;
  --bg: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle small"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="circle large"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic to calculate the delta between circle positions isn't quite right. You need to get the X and Y from the *centre* of each circle, then work out if the hypotenuse calculated from those two points is less than half of the combined radii.

Here's a working example. Note that I only added jQuery/jQueryUI to make dragging the circles around easier for testing - neither of these libraries are required for production use.

```js
let $label = $('.overlap-label span');

const hasOverlap = (x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1) => Math.hypot(x0 - x1, y0 - y1) <= r0 + r1;
const coordinates = (className) => {
  const el = document.querySelector(className);
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const radius = el.offsetHeight / 2;
  return {
    y: rect.top + radius,
    x: rect.left + radius,
    r: radius
  }
}
const checkForOverlap = () => {
  const cm = coordinates(".circle.small");
  const cl = coordinates(".circle.large");
  $label.text(hasOverlap(cm.x, cm.y, cm.r, cl.x, cl.y, cl.r));
}

$('.parent').draggable().on('drag', checkForOverlap);
```

```css
.circle {
  width: var(--square);
  height: var(--square);
  background: var(--bg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
}

.small {
  --square: 50px;
  --bg: red;
}

.large {
  --square: 100px;
  --bg: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="overlap-label">Circles are overlapping? <span>false</span></div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle small"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="circle large"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help - note that I just edited the answer to clean it up a little.

Comment: What if one of the div is square? how can i deal with that?